# OpenAi API invalid_request_error: you must provide a model parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, openai-api, chatgpt-api

maybe someone can help me, i got this Api Request, and its working with
"**gpt-3.5-turbo**" as
the "**model**" with this API Endpoint "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", but as soon as i change it to "**gpt-4 turbo**", i got this error message, (look down) and i don't understand why, because it should be good with the same API Endpoint(https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation):

`"{ "error": { "message": "invalid model ID", "type": "invalid_request_error", "param": null, "code": null } } "`

```
            try {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
                    vorlagenText = vorlagenText + selektierterText;
                    var settings = chatGptSettings;
                    ValidateParameter((ChatGptSettings)settings);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {chatGPT_ApiKey}");
                    var requestData = new {
                        max_tokens = chatGptSettings.MaxTokens,
                        temperature = chatGptSettings.Temperatur,
                        model = "gpt-4 turbo",
                        messages = new[] {
                                new { role = "user", content = vorlagenText }
                        }
                    };
                    var requestContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(chatGptSettings.ChatGptUrl, requestContent);
                    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Maybe someone can help me, thank you even if just trying :D

I'm expecting an answer from ChatGPT as i get it with the model "gpt-3.5-turbo" because it has the same Api Endpoint, i tried to change the URL, the API Endpoint to the older one, but thats not working, and this is the only new One i can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model name you want to use right now to get the GPT4 Turbo model is `gpt-4-1106-preview`. Once that model is promoted from preview to production, it will be called something different, but check out this link for a list of other model names you might choose.

https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-4-and-gpt-4-turbo

Comment: Hey, thank you for your fast answer. Okay, I didnt know that, do you know which Api Endpoint it has to be for the gtp4 preview? Because with my Api Endpoint from above, the model is not found.. maybe im just blind @my code. {
    "error": {
        "message": "The model `gpt-4-1106-preview` does not exist or you do not have access to it. Learn more: https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7102672-how-can-i-access-gpt-4.",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": "model_not_found"
    }
}

Comment: Alright on the website u sent is the answer, i have to use the Endpoint Api of my example above, then its probably a mistake in my Code, have to look it up again, thank you for your answer you are helping a 1 year programmer real good!

Comment: Glad to help! and welcome!